# Avaya 9630 for SIP

Tags: ip, sip, telephony, avaya

Is there any way to make the [9630](http://www.avaya.com/usa/product/9600-series-ip-deskphones) Desktop Headset work just as a SIP IP telephone, without the extensive need for additional Avaya equipment. All of our infrastructure is Cisco and we may receive about 80 Avaya deivces and I am wondering if they would work just as an IP telephone, without any additional hardware from Avaya or messing with the configuration of the Cisco devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do support SIP, there is extensive documentation on avaya.com about the firmware:

https://devconnect.avaya.com/public/dyn/d_dyn.jsp?fn=534

http://www.avaya.com/uk/resource/assets/factsheet/LB3369_9600_SIP_R2_data_sheet.pdf